# View Cardinality with SELECT

Tags: postgresql, select, cardinality

How can I view the estimated cardinality of a SELECT query in PostgreSQL prior execution? Is there a way to do it with the EXPLAIN keyword?

Comment: Yes. As you say, by using the `EXPLAIN` command.

Comment: You cannot get the cardinality without execution except very specific cases. Even `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` executes the statement to retrieve the number of rows. Even a rough estimate of the size needs a very precise knowledge of the data and the query.

Comment: The estimated cardinality of a query can be obtained with the EXPLAIN statement. Its accuracy may not be great, specially in complex queries or when stats are not updated regularly, so use with caution. EXPLAIN ANALYZE will actually execute the query and will provide **actual cardinality** (not estimated anymore)